# Shader Editor not match selected material

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I selected the glass which is glass, but under the shading, all the nodes are the donuts. What did I do wrong that the nodes are not matching with the selection?

Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: maybe you've also given this material to the glass (which doesn't mean that it will be used by the object as long as you haven't assigned any face to it) and need to delete it in the material list?

Comment: how do i tell if these nodes been given to the glass? lol I have not learned how to delete material yet.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This material is pinned. Unpin it to work on other materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected an object. That does not necessarily select the material you intended to select on it. You need to do that in the Material tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

In order to assign materials to different parts of an object you need to select desired faces in edit mode and click assign in the Material tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

It is also quite important to name your materials appropriately. It might not be a problem for you now to have Material.001, Material.002 and Material.003, but once you work on anything more than a few objects with 3 or 4 materials, it will get very confusing if you don't name things. It's better to make a habit out of it.

Comment: I did, and Assigned, but in node editor, it is still showing the material of the donut. Thanks tho. :D

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. It works fine if I test it same as allways.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I am planning to redo the whole thing until i found out what caused this. Have a good weekend~

Comment: No please don't,everything is fine. You just mistakenly pinned the material,unpin it to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Click the pin/thumbtack icon [image]It's the pin next to material. It locks that specific material to the shader editor.